# Передача данных через usb между PC и Android

Tags: android, windows, usb

Всем доброго времени суток. Появилась необходимость передавать данные с компьютера, под управлением Windows, на Andoid через usb. Например, Idisplay или Air Display показывают второй экран через usb. Вопрос такой, что для этого не обходимо и в какую сторону копать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Режимы передачи бывают разные. Например, можно поднять сеть между андроидом и PC. Делается это переводом мобильника в режим модема.

Другой вариант - перевести мобилу в режим отладки. Но это небезопасно, так как:

- юзер должен лезть в настройки и включать все сам
- также он должен сделать себя разработчиком
- потом он забудет выключить дебаг, сунет мобилу в злобный компьютер подзарядиться, а данные с телефона угонит вирус.

В целом, затея гниловастая. Уж лучше передавать по wi-fi.

Comment: да я для себя "любимого" так что не страшно, выкладывать не буду. А насчет wi-fi уже имеется прога, но вот задержка великовата. Хочу уменьшить пинг.

Comment: А можно уточнить в циферках сколько эта *великовата*? И сколько нужно. И как вы определили, что это *пинг великоват*, а не *полоса пропускания маловата*?

Comment: @Пионерка есть приложение SoundWire, показывает задержку в мс. 25 мс средние. wifi не забит (соседей нет, а так же устройство одно).Нужно ну 5 мс. в играх такая задержка "жизни" стоит :))